# postgresql log into another table with on conflict

Tags: postgresql, triggers, unique, upsert

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 and I try to insert millions rows per day using bulk insert:

```
INSERT INTO "tours" as cst ("adults","country_id", "price") 
VALUES (3, 129, 80), (2, 119,120) 
on conflict (adults, country_id) do 
   update set price = EXCLUDED.price, updated_at = now() 
   where excluded.price < cst.price 
RETURNING ID;
```

If the price is lower, I will update row. I want to add `else` condition for logging prices that not updated. Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO "tours" as cst ("adults","country_id", "price") 
VALUES (3, 129, 80), (2, 119,120) 
on conflict (adults, country_id) 
   case when excluded.price < cst.price 
      then 
        do update set price = EXCLUDED.price, updated_at = now() 
      else 
        INSERT INTO "tours_price_logging" (price, created_at) 
        values (EXCLUDED.price, now()) end;
```

But I have error for this case:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "case"
```

I think about removing condition `where excluded.price < cst.price` from insert and move this logic to `trigger`, but later I will update row price with value from `tours_price_logging` and price maybe more then current.

So, I want to use upsert and bulk insert with logging.

Answer (score 2):

You need a trigger:

```
create or replace function before_update_on_tours()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if new.price >= old.price then
        insert into tours_price_logging (price, created_at) 
        values (new.price, now());
        return null;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_update_on_tours
before update on tours
for each row execute procedure before_update_on_tours();
```

When a new price is not lower than the old one the trigger inserts a row into the logging table and returns null, so no updates will be done on tours. 
With the trigger your query should look like this:

```
insert into tours as cst (adults,country_id, price) 
values (3, 129, 80), (2, 119, 90) 
on conflict (adults, country_id) do 
   update set price = excluded.price, updated_at = now() 
returning id;
```

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes I need to update price to price that more then current(from another query). Price have expiration time, when its expired, I get new price from `tours_price_logging` and it's can be more then current. So, this trigger is not for all my cases.

Comment: Or maybe I can skip trigger execution in query?

Comment: You can create *conditional* trigger using [`when (condition)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) clause. You should find a column on which you can set a condition to skip the trigger execution.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to move your CASE into the UPDATE. "ON CONFLICT" can do one of two things, nothing or update.

```
...ON CONFLICT (adults, country_id) UPDATE SET price = CASE WHEN ... ;
```