# My PSQL after insert trigger fails to insert into another table when ON DUPLICATE encounters a dupilcate

Tags: postgresql

I am slowly working through a feature where I am importing large csv files. The contents of the csv file has a chance that when it is uploaded the contents will trigger a uniqueness conflict. I've combed stack overflow for some similar resources but I still can't seem to get my trigger to update another table when a duplicate entry is found. The following code is what I have currently implemented with my line of logic for this process. Also, this is implemented in a rails app but the underlying sql is the following.

When a user uploads a file, the following happens when its processed.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE codes_temp ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM codes WITH NO DATA;

create or replace function log_duplicate_code() 
  returns trigger 
  language plpgsql 
  as 
$$
begin
    insert into duplicate_codes(id, campaign_id, code_batch_id, code, code_id, created_at, updated_at)
    values (gen_random_uuid(), excluded.campaign_id, excluded.code_batch_id, excluded.code, excluded.code_id, now(), now());
    return null;
end; 
$$

create trigger log_duplicate_code 
after insert on codes 
for each row execute procedure log_duplicate_code();

INSERT INTO codes SELECT * FROM codes_temp ct 
    ON CONFLICT (campaign_id, code) 
DO update set updated_at = excluded.updated_at;

DROP TRIGGER log_duplicate_code ON codes;
```

When I try to run this process nothing happens at all. If I were to have a csv file with this value `CODE01` and then upload again with `CODE01` the `duplicate_codes` table doesn't get populated at all and I don't understand why. There is no error that gets triggered or anything so it seems like `DO UPATE.....` is doing something. What am I missing here?

I also have some questions that come to my mind even if this were to work as intended. For example, I am uploading millions of these codes, etc.

1). Should my trigger be a statement trigger instead of a row for scalability?

2). What if someone else tries to upload another file that has millions of codes? I have my code wrapped in a transaction. Would a new separate trigger be created? Will this conflict with a previously processing process?

**####### EDIT #1 #######**

Thanks to Adriens' comment I do see that `After Insert` does not have the `OLD` key phrase. I updated my code to use `EXCLUDED` and I receive the following error for the trigger.

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "excluded" (PG::UndefinedTable)
```

Finally, here are the S.O. posts I've used to try to tailor my code but I just can't seem to make it work.

**####### EDIT #2 #######**

I have a little more context on to how this is implemented.

When the CSV is loaded, a staging table called `codes_temp` is created and dropped at the end of the transaction. This table contains no unique constraints. From what I read only the actual table that I want to insert `codes` should have the unique constraint error.

In my `INSERT` statement, the `DO update set updated_at = excluded.updated_at;` doesn't trigger a unique constraint error. As of right now, I don't know if it should or not. I borrowed this logic taken from this s.o. question [postgresql log into another table with on conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097824/postgresql-log-into-another-table-with-on-conflict) it seemed to me like I had to update something if I specify the `DO UPDATE SET` clause.

Last, the correct criteria for codes in the database is the following:

For example, this is an example entry in my `codes` table

```
id, campaign_id, code
1,  1,           CODE01
2,  1,           CODE02
3,  1,           CODE03
```

If any of these codes appear again somewhere, This should not be inserted into the `codes` table but it needs to be inserted into the `duplicate_codes` table because they were already uploaded before.

```
id, campaign_id, code
1,  1,           CODE01.  
2,  1,           CODE02
3,  1,           CODE03
```

As for the `codes_temp` table I don't have any unique constraints, so there is no criteria to select the right one.

[postgresql log into another table with on conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097824/postgresql-log-into-another-table-with-on-conflict)

[Postgres insert on conflict update using other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39950624/postgres-insert-on-conflict-update-using-other-table)

[Postgres on conflict - insert to another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336081/postgres-on-conflict-insert-to-another-table)

[How to do INSERT INTO SELECT and ON DUPLICATE UPDATE in PostgreSQL 9.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663280/how-to-do-insert-into-select-and-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql-9-5)

Comment: If you are looking for duplicates, are you sure `if new.code <> old.code then` is the answer? To me that is looking for `code` that differs, not that is the same.

Comment: Took a second look and realized you are creating a `after insert on codes` trigger. This `new.code <> old.code` will fail as `INSERT` triggers don't have an `OLD.*` tuple.

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver thank your quick replies. Can you recommend how this should work? For example, I based alot of this code from this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097824/postgresql-log-into-another-table-with-on-conflict. Im confused if whether the correct way to do this is with new/old or excluded. The difference I see is that the trigger in that answer is using before update but I'm not updating a previous uploaded. Im creating new records

Comment: What about an update trigger?

Comment: `EXCLUDED` is only available in the `ON CONFLICT` clause, not in a trigger function.

Comment: This needs more information 1) `INSERT INTO codes SELECT * FROM codes_temp ct ...`. Is `codes_temp` a staging table with no constraints where the CSV is initially loaded into? 2) If `ON CONFLICT (campaign_id, code)` why on a conflict do you only change `updated_at`, does that not still result in a `UNIQUE` conflict as you have changed neither `campaign_id` or `code`?  3) If there are more then one  `(campaign_id, code)` in `codes_temp` what is the criteria for the correct one?  Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver I updated my answer, I hope this adds more helpful context. Basically as the insert happens, I just need whatver is duplicated to be logged into another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me something like:

```
INSERT INTO 
   codes 
SELECT 
   distinct on(campaign_id, code) * 
FROM 
   codes_temp ct 
ORDER BY
  campaign_id, code, id DESC;
```

Assuming `id` was assigned sequentially, the above would select the most recent row into `codes`.

Then:

```
INSERT INTO 
    duplicate_codes 
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
   codes_temp AS ct
LEFT JOIN 
   codes 
ON 
   ct.id = codes.id
WHERE 
   codes.id IS NULL;
```

The above would select the rows in `codes_temp` that where not selected into `codes` into the duplicates table.

Obviously not tested on your data set. I would create a small test data set that has uniqueness conflicts and test with.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help. With you answer I just had to tweak some stuff here and there but ultimately I got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Adrian Klaver, I just thought of something as a quick follow up. Does your answer require the trigger anymore if I can just insert directly?

Comment: No it should not as you are doing the work in the queries directly. As I mentioned in my answer create a test data set and verify that the queries do what you want.